# .NET LINQ to Entities base where clause for generic Type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity Framework to access my domain models, all of which implement an interface (IPublishable) that specifies properties to indicate whether an item has been published.

When accessing items from the front end I always want to filter out unpublished items. So, every time I write a query I'm doing something similar to this (where the following DbSets Objects1 and Objects2 both implement `IPublishable`

```
context.Objects1.Where( x => x.IsPublished ...).OrderBy( x => x.Id).ToList()
context.Objects2.Where( x => x.IsPublished ...).First()
```

What would be ideal is if I could inject the common `Where()` clause into all my queries within my web app OR if there was a way to write an extension method which I could include in each query.

I tried to create the extension method for all linq queries

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FrontEnd<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet) where T : class {
  return dbSet.Cast<IPublishable>().Where( x => x.IsPublished ...).Cast<T>();
}
```

And use like this...

```
context.Objects1.FrontEnd().Where( x => ...).OrderBy(...
```

However I get the error "LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types"

I'm new to EF, so any information would be a great help.
Thanks

Comment: I would think some kind of [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) could be created for this.

Comment: To accomplish something similar I ended up using dynamic linq. But that was only for a specific subset of data, not "all linq queries" as you need, so I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I think the true answer I was looking for was a Repository based interim between my App and Entity framework in which I could intercept queries and add on the base where clause I was using in all my queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED as per comments - this works

```
public static IQueryable<T> FrontEnd<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet)
    where T : class, IPublishable
{
    return dbSet.Where(x => x.IsPublished);
}
```

and can be used like this:

```
context.Objects1.FrontEnd().Where( x => ...).OrderBy(...
```

---

You can try either of these options:

```
public static IQueryable<dynamic> FrontEnd(this DbSet<dynamic> dbSet)
{
    return dbSet.Where(x => (x as IPublishable).IsPublished);
}
```

or

```
public static IQueryable<T> FrontEnd<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet)
    where T : class, IPublishable
{
    return dbSet.Where(x => x.IsPublished);
}
```

note:

the first option uses dynamic so is slower
with the second option you have to specify the type in the call to FrontEnd()
e.g.

```
context.Objects1.FrontEnd<Objects1>().Where( x => ...).OrderBy(...
```

Comment: This is excellent, just what I've been searching for! I implemented suggestion 2 and found that I didn't have to specify the `<type>`.. looking at the example you've given and my code, I'm sure they're identical? Not that I'm complaining :)

Answer (score 0):

I think LINQ to Entities does not know how to match the cast operator to SQL request. As a suggestion, you could try something like that:

```
IEnumerable<IPublishable> ReadPublishable(Expression<Func<DomainModelType, bool>> condition)
```

The expression act as a predicate. So you pass to the ReadPublishable function a predicate that filters the IPublishable objects you need. I tried successfully but only on simple predicates so,  I do not know whether that works if you make use of "is" or "as" operators.